# How to define a flow in Tshark?

Tags: wireshark, tshark

I want to use Tshark as a subprocess and I need to define a flow to display its packets, but I don't know the cmd to define a flow in tshark, just I know it in wireshark:

```
ip.src == ipAddr and ip.dst == ipAddrDst and udp.srcport == 33191 and udp.dstport == 2003 ;
```

So can you help me to find the equivalent cmd in tshark?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use tcpdump's syntax:

```
tshark "ip and udp and src host ipAddr and dst host ipAddrDst \
        and src port 33191 and dst port 2003"
```